# spring test fails on mockServletContext unsupportedOperation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a set of Integration Tests running for my Spring-Boot 1.3 app.  But I had to add the following to get my maximum sessions working:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements ServletContextAware {

...
 @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {

        servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setHttpOnly(true);

        // causes an ApplicationEvent to be published to the Spring ApplicationContext every time a HttpSession commences or terminates
        servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

...
}
```

Now when I run my tests, I get the following:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in file [/Users/davidclark/projects/edmtotal/build/classes/main/com/edelweissco/dental/configuration/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)

...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext.addListener(MockServletContext.java:675)
    at com.edelweissco.dental.configuration.WebSecurityConfig.setServletContext(WebSecurityConfig.java:123)
...
```

Here is an example test class (but they all fall with the same exception):

```
@Transactional
public class ConfigurationSettingsTest extends BaseSpecification {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationSettings configurationSettings;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context

...
}
```

where BaseSpecification is:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApp, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class BaseSpecification extends Specification {

    @Value('${local.server.port}')
    private int serverPort;

    def setup() {
        RestAssured.port = serverPort;
    }
}
```

It would seem that now when I run my integration tests, a MockServlet is being applied here, and it doesn't support. this feature.  When debugging, I see that a SpringBootMockServletContext is trying to be set in setServletContext, and that is where the exception is.

Answer (score 1):

I will post my answer in case anyone else runs into this.  The problem was in my BaseSpecification.  I added the @WebAppConfiguration and @IntegrationTest to it, and removed @IntegrationTest off the individual integration tests.  Apparently this will actually create the ServletContext the way it should be.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApp, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class BaseSpecification extends Specification {
```